# Converting a bag with uncompressed Images to CompressedImages

Tags: ros, rosbag, offline, compressedimage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an offline program that will bag.write sensor_msgs/Image and would rather compress them into a smaller format (e.g. JPEG) for easier streaming.  Compressing the bags with bz2 or lz4 is insufficient.  How do I do this offline (without using compressed image transport and publishing/subscribing) in C++ (for initial creation) and/or Python (post processing script on existing bags)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209448/converting-a-bag-with-uncompressed-images-to-compressedimages/) by [EEngineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/14886/eengineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to compress the image in your code like the compressed image transport does.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0